# Open config xml file from path C#

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, config

How to open from path, for example, "config/appconfig.xml", file like this

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="String setting" value="String retrieved from App.Config"/>
        <add key="Date setting" value="Thursday, December 01, 2005 12:53:56 PM"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I can't find any solution in `System.Configuration` namespace. Pelease help:)

Comment: Use `Environment` and `Application` static classes to access relative paths and **serialization** to read XML data

Comment: go to references in solution explorer and open .net tab then add system.Configuration dll

Answer (score 0):

go to references in solution explorer and open .net tab then add system.Configuration dll

Comment: How it help me? Me need to open it not in VS but in my class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("config/appconfig.xml");
```